# Basement hydro or aquaponics?

Tags: indoors, hydroponic, aquaponic

What I want to grow:

- Cherry tomatoes
- Iceberg & Romaine lettuce
- Green/Yellow peppers
- Strawberries

Room information:

- 55-75% RH, can be vented to the outside once a day manually (via a dryer pipe and a computer fan)
- 15 to 20 degrees celsius from night to day
- 200-400W of T5 high output fixtures

## Question

Would hydro or aquaponics be a more suitable solution and what style, In media, Raft, PCV Pipe?

Do those 4 plants play nicely together or should I do a media/PVC setup to separate some?

Comment: Can we assume that your temperature info is in degrees Celsius?

Comment: @Shane Yes it is sorry, lol does anything even grow in -10?

Comment: I've seen all of these plants in hydroponic setups and I think they would be fine together.  None of them have invasive roots.  Your main issue will be competition for light.  Strawberries and lettuce are low to the ground, while tomatoes and peppers grow up tall or viney…especially tomatoes.  If you can give the tomatoes enough space when you plant them to fill out without blocking out the light from the lettuce and strawberries, I think you'll be fine.

Comment: From own experiments, tomatoes and peppers grow just fine in passive hydro (clay pebbles), while lettuce seemed to work best in aero (fog/spray, or nutrient film if you don't mind the extra effort).

Answer (score 4):

How many plants? 400w is fine for a 3x3 area but not for a larger setup, especially if you have different heights of plants.

T5 will struggle to get tomatoes the level of light required. I would figure a 400-600w HPS or MH light in.

Factor in support for the tall plants, either up to the basement ceiling or some caging/netting.